# RxJS websockets sending 'undefined' messages

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, rxjs, ws

I have angular frontend using RxJS websockets and a node.js backend using the 'ws' package.

The problem I am having is that no messages are being transmitted from the backend to the front end - there is a connection as I can force them to interact, and my Angular frontend messages are always received by the backend properly.

The issue is the backend messages are not being received by the front end, so for example - this is my backend code...

```
clients = [];
wss;

webSocketServer() {
    this.wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 7072 });

    this.wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
        const id = methods.generateRandomId(5);
        this.clients.push({socket: ws, data: { id }});
        
        ws.on('open', () => {
            console.log(`Client ${id} has connected.`)
            this.sendWebsockMessage(`User ${id} connected...`);
        });

        ws.on('message', (msg) => {
            const message = JSON.parse(msg);         
            console.log(message);
        });
        
        ws.on('close', () => {
            console.log(`Client ${id} has disconnected.`)
        })

    })
}

sendWebsockMessage(msg) {
    this.clients.forEach(client =>{
        client.socket.send(`[{hello: hi}]`);
    });
}
```

The problems are:

- Client ${id} has connected does not display, which seems to imply the 'open' routine doesn't run.
- On the front end the output is always undefined. It doesn't seem to matter what I put in that sendWebsockMessage function - the output is always undefined.

This is my front-end, Angular code:

```
ws: WebSocketSubject<any>;

webSockets(): void {
// deserializer is from this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4166
// this solves a connection issue
this.ws = webSocket({url: `${environment.websocketUrl}`, deserializer: () => {}});

// this.sendMessage(ws, 'loginNotification', 'hello');

this.ws.subscribe(
  {
    next: (message: string) => {
      console.log(`msg: ${message}`);
  },
    error: (error) => {
      console.log(`Error in socket: ${error}`);
  },
    complete: () => {
      console.log("connection to server closed");
    }
 });
}

sendTestMessage(): void {
  this.ws.next({ msg: 'hello' });
}
```

All this code gives me is `msg: undefined` from the next: section of the subscription. If I hit the 'sendTestMessage' function then that object is recieved in string form on the node.js server.

Comment: Are you calling webSocketServer() somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, and I have console logged it right up until the point I call the client.socket.send and all looks as expected. It's just a string which looks correct before being sent but arrives as undefined.

Comment: Could you pls try change your **sendTestMessage** function with `this.ws.next({ message: 'hello' });`

Comment: The sendTestMessage function cant be changed really, as its called from a button. It has to be in a function I think... but this part does work, frontend to backend communicates fine, its the backend to frontend where the message becomes undefined.

Comment: So I took out the deserializer and for some reason the error did not come back and the whole thing worked. I do not know what happened, except for trial and error!